# Passport Facebook - Can't get my head around sending a token

Tags: angularjs, node.js, facebook, passport.js, passport-facebook

UPDATED: Current solution below.

I'm adding facebook login into my website - something I was hoping to be simple but proving difficult.

(Built with: Node.js/Express API and Angular front end)

So my issues I kindly ask help with:

**1 - Instead of successRedirect return a token**

I'm using `passport-facebook` to help with the login process however in the callback instead of the successRedirect can i just say return some json containing a token. Note the token is a JWT one that i already use with standard email authentication and I currently create this in the `passport.serializeUser`:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  var token = ///implementation for token
  done(null, user);
});
```

And then in the callback do something like:

```
router.get('/login/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', {
     res.json({success: true, token:token)
  })
);
```

**2 - How do handle on the client side**

Then the second bit i can't get my head around is if i return the token, on my client side I'll be 'picking' that up in a usual `$http.get` method. But how will the URL flow work - by this I mean i have a 'login with facebook' button, this then calls the server side `router.get('/login/facebook'` which redirects to the facebook login page so once thats done and a token is returned how will it know to go back to the home page.

Hope my questions above make sense - am new to Angular so please excuse me if not clear will to best i can to explain.

---

SOLUTION (please let me know your thoughts if there is something bad I'm doing)
So after some more thought, I've solved this using the following:

1 - In the callback I made a new API get route. I then send the user ID in the URL to create my custom JWT token:

```
router.get('/login/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook',
          { session: false, failureRedirect: "/processfblogin/false"  }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect("/api/processfblogin/" + req.user._id);
  }
);
```

Then from here i make the token and send in the URL.

So this is where it got interesting. I ideally wanted to use a `$http` get however CORs kept giving me a 302. So eventually I attached the token as a URL parameter and send it as:

```
res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/#/fbToProcess/' + token);
```

I then made this single page with its own controller that simply takes the token, saves it and everything auth wise clicks on my page.

I'll continue looking for a way to send the token in a json response so the user doesnt need to go to this new empty page however until then it works :-)

Comment: So I've got a potential solution I'll update my question now - if could someone could let me know your thoughts on this approach.